# Tie skaffold profile to namespace

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

Is there a way to tie a skaffold profile to a namespace? I'd like to make sure that dev, staging and prod deployments always go to the right namespace. I know that I can add a namespace to `skaffold run` like `skaffold run -p dev -n dev` but that's a little error prone. I'd like to make my builds even safer by tying profiles to namespaces.

I've tried adding the following to my `skaffold.yaml` based on the fact that there's a path in `skaffold.yaml` which is [`build/cluster/namespace`](https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/yaml/) but I suspect I'm misunderstanding the purpose of the cluster spec.

```
profiles:
- name: local
  patches:
  - op: replace
    path: /build/artifacts/0/cluster/namespace
    value: testing
```

but I get the error

```
 ❮❮❮ skaffold render -p local
FATA[0000] creating runner: applying profiles: applying profile local: invalid path: /build/artifacts/0/cluster/namespace
```

I've tried other variants of changing the cluster namespace but all of them fail.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce it and will get back to you once I find something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### if TL/DR: please go directly to "solution" (the last section)

> Is there a way to tie a skaffold profile to a namespace? I'd like to
>   make sure that dev, staging and prod deployments always go to the
>   right namespace. I know that I can add a namespace to `skaffold run`
>   like `skaffold run -p dev -n dev` but that's a little error prone. I'd
>   like to make my builds even safer by tying profiles to namespaces.

At the beginning we need to clarify two things, namely if we are talking about `namespaces` in `build` or `deploy` stage of the pipeline. On one hand you write, that you want *to make sure that dev, staging and prod **deployments** always go to the right namespace* so I'm assuming you're rather interested in setting the appropriate `namespace` on your **kubernetes cluster** in which built images will be eventually deployed. Hovewer later you mentioned also about *making **builds** even safer by tying profiles to namespaces*. Please correct me if I'm wrong but my guess is that you rather mean `namespaces` at the `deploy` stage.

So answering your question: **yes, it is possible to tie a skaffold profile to a specific namespace**.

> I've tried adding the following to my `skaffold.yaml` based on the
>   fact that there's a path in `skaffold.yaml` which is
>   [build/cluster/namespace](https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/yaml/) but I suspect I'm misunderstanding the
>   purpose of the cluster spec.

You're right, there is such path in `skaffold.yaml` but then your example should look as follows:

```
profiles:
- name: local
  patches:
  - op: replace
    path: /build/cluster/namespace
    value: testing
```

Note that `cluster` element is on the same indentation level as `artifacts`. As you can read in the [reference](https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/yaml/):

```
cluster:    #   beta describes how to do an on-cluster build.
```

and as you can see, most of its options are related with `kaniko`. It can be also `patched` in the same way as other `skaffold.yaml` elements in specific `profiles` but anyway I don't think this is the element you're really concerned about so let's leave it for now.

Btw. you can easily validate your `skaffold.yaml` syntax by runnig:

```
skaffold fix
```

If every element is properly used, all the indentation levels are correct etc. it will print:

```
config is already latest version
```

otherwise something like the error below:

```
FATA[0000] creating runner: applying profiles: applying profile prod: invalid path: /build/cluster/namespace
```

---

## solution

You can make sure your deployments go to the right namespace by setting `kubectl flags`. It assumes you're using `docker` as `builder` and `kubectl` as deployer. As there are plenty of different `builders` and `deployers` supported by `skaffold` the e.g. you deploy with `helm` the detailed solution may look quite different.

**One very important caveat:** the path must be already present in your general config part, otherwise you won't be able to patch it in `profiles` section e.g.:

if you have in your profiles section following `patch`:

```
profiles:
- name: prod
  patches:
  - op: replace
    path: /build/artifacts/0/docker/dockerfile
    value: DifferentNameForDockerfile
```

following section must be already present in your `skaffold.yaml`:

```
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: skaffold-example
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile # the pipeline will fail at build stage
```

Going back to our `namaspaces`, first we need to set default values in `deploy` section:

```
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - k8s-pod.yaml
    flags:
      global: # additional flags passed on every command.
      - --namespace=default
#     apply: # additional flags passed on creations (kubectl apply).
#     - --namespace=default
#     delete: # additional flags passed on deletions (kubectl delete).
#     - --namespace=default
```

I set only `global` flags but this is also possible to set for `apply` and `delete` commands separately.

In next step we need to override our default value (they must be already present, so we can override them) in our `profiles`:

```
profiles:
- name: dev
  patches:
  - op: replace
    path: /deploy/kubectl/flags/global/0
    value: --namespace=dev
- name: staging
  patches:
  - op: replace
    path: /deploy/kubectl/flags/global/0
    value: --namespace=staging
- name: prod
  patches:
  - op: replace
    path: /deploy/kubectl/flags/global/0
    value: --namespace=prod
```

Then we can run:

```
skaffold run --render-only --profile=prod
```

As we can see our `Pod` is going to be deployed in `prod` `namespace` of our **kubernetes cluster**:

```
Generating tags...
 - skaffold-example -> skaffold-example:v1.3.1-15-g11d005d-dirty
Checking cache...
 - skaffold-example: Found Locally
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: skaffold-v1.3.1
    skaffold.dev/builder: local
    skaffold.dev/cleanup: "true"
    skaffold.dev/deployer: kubectl
    skaffold.dev/docker-api-version: "1.39"
    skaffold.dev/profile.0: prod
    skaffold.dev/run-id: b83d48db-aec8-4570-8cb8-dbf9a7795c00
    skaffold.dev/tag-policy: git-commit
    skaffold.dev/tail: "true"
  name: getting-started
  namespace: prod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: skaffold-example:3e4840dfd2ad13c4d32785d73641dab66be7a89b43355eb815b85bc09f45c8b2
    name: getting-started
```