# Tie skaffold profile to cluster

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

Building off another one of my questions about [tying profiles to namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60061593/tie-skaffold-profile-to-namespace), is there a way to tie profiles to clusters?

I've found a couple times now that I accidentally run commands like `skaffold run -p local -n skeleton` when my current kubernetes context is pointing to `docker-desktop`. I'd like to prevent myself and other people on my team from committing the same mistake.

I found that there's a way of [specifying contexts](https://skaffold.dev/docs/environment/kube-context/) but that doesn't play nicely if developers use custom contexts like `kubeclt set-context custom --user=custom --cluster=custom`. I've also found a [cluster field](https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/yaml/) in the `skaffold.yaml` reference but it seems that doesn't satisfy my need because it doesn't let me specify a cluster name.

Comment: Could you explain what would be the desired state you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want to make sure that if I run `skaffold -p prod` skaffold will fail if my kubecontext points to a cluster other than my production cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging through the [skaffold documentation](https://skaffold.dev/docs/) and performing several tests I finally managed to find at least partial solution of your problem, maybe not the most elegant one, but still functional. If I find a better way I will edit my answer.

Let's start from the beginning:

As we can read [here](https://skaffold.dev/docs/environment/kube-context/):

> When interacting with a Kubernetes cluster, just like any other
>   Kubernetes-native tool, Skaffold requires a valid Kubernetes context
>   to be configured. The selected kube-context determines the Kubernetes
>   cluster, the Kubernetes user, and the default namespace. By default,
>   Skaffold uses the current kube-context from your kube-config file.

This is quite important point as we are actually starting from `kube-context` and based on it we are able to trigger specific profile, never the oposite.

**important to remember**: `kube-context` is not activated based on the `profile` but the opposite is true: the specific `profile` is triggered based on the current context (selected by `kubectl config use-context`).

Although we can overwrite default settings from our `skaffold.yaml` config file by patching ([compare related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60061593/tie-skaffold-profile-to-namespace/60107468#60107468)), it's not possible to overwrite the `current-context` based on slected `profile` e.g. manually as in your command:

```
skaffold -p prod
```

Here you are manually selecting specific `profile`. This way you bypass automatic [profile triggering](https://skaffold.dev/docs/environment/profiles/). As the documentation says:

> **Activations in skaffold.yaml**: You can auto-activate a profile based on
>
> - kubecontext (could be either a string or a regexp: prefixing with `!` will negate the match)
> - environment variable value
> - skaffold command (dev/run/build/deploy)

Let's say we want to activate our profile based on current `kube-context` only to make it simple however we can join different conditions together by AND and OR like in the example [here](https://skaffold.dev/docs/environment/profiles/).

#### solution

> I want to make sure that if I run skaffold -p prod skaffold will fail
>   if my kubecontext points to a cluster other than my production
>   cluster.

I'm affraid it cannot be done this way. If you've already manually selected `prod profile` by `-p prod` you're bypassing selection of profile based on current context therefore you already chosen **what can be done** no matter how **where it can be done** is set (currently selected `kube-context`). **In this situation `skaffold` doesn't have any mechanisms that would prevent you from running something on wrong cluster**. In other words you're forcing this way certain behaviour of your pipeline. You already agree to it by selecting the profile. If you gave up using `-p` or `--profile` flags, certain profiles will never be triggerd unless currently selected `kube-context` does it automatically. `skaffold` just won't let that happen.

Let's look at the following example showing how to make it work:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: getting-started
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: skaffold-example
    docker:
      dockerfile: NonExistingDockerfile # the pipeline will fail at build stage
  cluster:
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - k8s-pod.yaml
    flags:
      global: # additional flags passed on every command.
      - --namespace=default
  kubeContext: minikube
profiles:
- name: prod
  patches:
  - op: replace
    path: /build/artifacts/0/docker/dockerfile
    value: Dockerfile
  - op: replace
    path: /deploy/kubectl/flags/global/0
    value: --namespace=prod
  activation:
  - kubeContext: minikube
    command: run 
  - kubeContext: minikube
    command: dev
```

In general part of our `skaffold.yaml` config we configured:

```
dockerfile: NonExistingDockerfile # the pipeline will fail at build stage
```

Untill we name our `Dockerfile` - `"NonExistingDockerfile"` every pipeline will fail at its `build` stage. So by default all builds, no matter what `kube-context` is selected are destined to fail. Hovewer we can override this default behaviour by `patching` specific fragment of the `skaffold.yaml` in our `profile` section and setting again `Dockerfile` to its standard name. This way every:

```
skaffold run
```

or

```
skaffold dev
```

command will succeed only if the current `kube-context` is set to `minikube`. Otherwise it will fail.

We can check it with:

```
skaffold run --render-only
```

previously setting our current `kube-context` to the one that matches what is present in the `activation` section of our `profile` definition.

> I've found a couple times now that I accidentally run commands like
>   `skaffold run -p local -n skeleton` when my current kubernetes context
>   is pointing to `docker-desktop`. I'd like to prevent myself and other
>   people on my team from committing the same mistake.

I understand your point that it would be nice to have some built-in mechanism that prevents overriding this automatic profile activation configured in `skaffold.yaml` by command line options, but it looks like currently it isn't possible. If you don't specify `-p local`, `skaffold` will always choose the correct profile based on the current `context`. Well, it looks like good material for **feature request**.

Comment: This happened to me too - a lot! Activations are a good solution for this problem but it's still not ideal. 

Have you looked at DevSpace? https://github.com/devspace-cloud/devspace It's very similar to skaffold but it remembers your kube-context and prints a warning if you are deploying to a different one than last time. It waits for about 10s before continuing after the warning which gives you enough time to abord the deployment.

Comment: Thanks @LukasGentele, it looks like a really interesting alternative. Definitely worth trying out!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to lock down the kubeContext for Skaffold both ways with:

```
skaffold dev --profile="dev-cluster-2" --kube-context="dev-cluster-2"
```

I also set in skaffold.yaml:

```yaml
profiles:
- name: dev-cluster-2
  activation:
    - kubeContext: dev-cluster-2
  deploy:
    kubeContext: dev-cluster-2
```

*It seems* that using this combination is telling `skaffold` explicitly enough to not use the `currentContext` of `$KUBECONFIG`. With this combination, if `--kube-context` is missing from the cli parameters, the `activation` step in `skaffold.yaml` will trigger an error message if `currentContext` in `$KUBECONFIG` differs from the expected kubeContext of the activated Skaffold profile.

Hope this helps fellow developers who feel the pain when skaffold randomly switches the current kubernetes cluster, if the `currentContext` in `$KUBECONFIG` is changed as a side-effect from eg. another terminal window.